# XlsxWriter not saving formatting changes

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, xlsxwriter

I'm attempting to create a series of specifically formatted Excel files with multiple sheets using Python in Databricks, looping through each sheet and applying the formatting. I'm able to import the data in my pandas dataframes perfectly and output the Excels. However, I'm unable to modify the format. Nothing is saving, and I don't know why, as I get no errors.

Here is the module of code within my larger loop that is giving me the problem:

```
  with pd.ExcelWriter(fname, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    pcpop.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s1, startrow = 6)
    estgmp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s2, startrow = 6)
    jcwpp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s3, startrow = 6)
    cppan.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s4, startrow = 6)
    aigmp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s5, startrow = 6)
    pcmtp.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s6, startrow = 6)
    cpppan.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=s7, startrow = 6)
# Everything above works fine. Nothing below errors, but neither does it do anything
  workbook = writer.book
  while sh < 7:
    print(sh)
    sn = slist[sh]
    sc = sclist[sh] + 6
    sc = str(sc)
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sn]
    worksheet.write('A1', 'KPI', {'bold':True})
    worksheet.write('A2', 'Bodyshop Reference', {'bold':True})
    worksheet.write('A3', 'Date', {'bold':True})
    worksheet.write('B1', sn)
    worksheet.write('B2', xlname)
    worksheet.write('B3', ts)
    worksheet.add_table('A6:B' + sc)
    sh = sh + 1

  filepath = "//Report/" + xlname + ts + ".xlsx"
  sftp.put(fname,filepath)
```

The only clue I have is that when I add workbook close() I get a UserWarning about calling close() on an already closed file. Hardcoding and removing everything from the while loop also does not work, as cutting everything down to something as simple as the below makes no impact either. Changing the hardcoded sheet name throws an error, so I know it's referencing the writer.book. However, none of the changes show up. My guess is that Databricks is creating an ephemeral copy of the Excel report that doesn't overwrite the original, but I've no clue how to reference that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
worksheet = writer.sheets['Paint Cost By Operator']
worksheet.write('A1', 'KPI')
filepath = "//Report/" + xlname + ts + ".xlsx"
sftp.put(fname,filepath)
```

Edit: Got it to work by putting everything into the with. I'd tried Jmcnamara's solution of indenting into the with initially, only to be thrown an error around dict objects. Since the code worked while isolated, I'd assumed it was a limitation of the library. However, upon second look, the shortcut I'd taken of not passing a dedicated format object was causing the problem. Removing the bold dict got it to work. Thanks!

Comment: I looked into this as well and it looks possible but I haven't seen anything concrete and testable. I usually use a combination of xlsxwriter to create/overwrite a file with multiple sheets or separated tables, and then use openpyxl to make adjustments to format and individual values. Is it possible for you to recode this so that the while-loop your using goes before or during and can be written by xlsxwriter with the rest of the sheet? I've made similiar loops like this into dataframes and just had them written as starting at x, and then having the next sheet start at row len(dataframe)+n.

Comment: I don't know if it is a copy and paste formatting issue but the `workbook = writer.book` code is outside the `with` context manager which means that the Excel file is probably already closed (at the end of the `with` scope) and not modifiable. Try move that code in 1 indentation level.

Comment: try workbook.save(filepath)